# How to make data in Widget reactive?

Tags: flutter

I have widget that evaluate data from streams. I want to make displaying this data reactive:

```
class BuilderLoading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    // apiProv.getToken();
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: apiProv.resultController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          String tokenLoadingState = '';
          String regionsLoadingState = '';
          String industryLoadingState = '';

          if (snapshot.data is ApiKeyLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Progress:
                tokenLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Done:
                tokenLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case ApiKeyLoadingState.Error:
                tokenLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }
          }

          else if (snapshot.data is RegionsLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case RegionsLoadingState.Progress:
                regionsLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case RegionsLoadingState.Done:
                regionsLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case RegionsLoadingState.Error:
                regionsLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }
          }

          else if (snapshot.data is IndustryLoadingState) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case IndustryLoadingState.Progress:
                industryLoadingState = "Loading";
                break;
              case IndustryLoadingState.Done:
                industryLoadingState = "Done";
                break;
              case IndustryLoadingState.Error:
                industryLoadingState = "Error";
                break;
              default:
                return Text("Unknown");
            }    
          }       

          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Loading token $tokenLoadingState"),
              Text("Loading regions $regionsLoadingState"),
              Text("Loading industry $industryLoadingState"),
            ],
          );


        });
  }
}
```

But there is issue with logic, that I do not know how to solve. After getting `tokenLoadingState` I want to display that it status, than I am getting `regionsLoadingState` and I want to display `tokenLoadingState` and it together.

But it's seems that widget redrawing every time, and I see only:

```
Loading token Done
Loading regions
Loading industry
```

then:

```
Loading token 
Loading regions Done
Loading industry
```

then

```
Loading token 
Loading regions
Loading industry Done
```

Also I need some way to evaluate if all conditions are Done and switch to `HomePage();`

Comment: What exactly is your "issue with logic"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigate into `home` if all all conditions are fullfilled, you must create another state inside your BLoC, so obviusly you'll check it first in condition tree otherwise won't be executed. After that:

```
if(snapshot.data is AllConditionsDone){
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).push('home');
  });
}
```

Share more about logic problem so we can help.

Comment: I updated questing. How `AllConditionsDone` should be done?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov it's about your bloc file, if you share it we can help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you are only setting the `tokenLoadingState` in each of the branches, `regionsLoadingState` and `industryLoadingState` stay initialized to the empty String.

As for your goal of evaluating multiple conditions, I would recommend one of these solutions:

- Wrap your data in a container class that contains all three states
- Separate each state into a different stream and use nested `StreamBuilder`s.

Comment: Obviously, the stream's state can only be one instance at a time. Do the provided options not work for you for some reason?

Comment: Why you suggesting use nested StreamBuilder? 
it's look like I found problem. I did Widget StateFull